# Escaping "[" in css selector beatifulsoup python

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, escaping, selector

This is my input:

```
input autocomplete="off" id="one-step-full-name" name="user[name]"
```

When I try:

```
BeautifulSoup.select('input[name=user\[name\]]')
```

I get:

```
lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1477, in select 'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token) ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "input[name=user[name]]"
```

BeatifulSoup ver 4.6.0

What's wrong with the escaping?

Comment: Not familiar with BeautifulSoup, but you could try escaping with the hex code of the offending characters. `'input[name=user\5Bname\5D]'`

Answer (score 1):

In the 606 line of the element.py:

```
r'=?"?(?P<value>[^\]"]*)"?\]$'
```

The right bracket symbol(]) cannot exist in double quotes("").

you can try:

```
'input[name*=\\"user\[name]'
```